# Points of Weil restriction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $l/k$ be a finite separable extension of fields. Let $X$ be an $k$-scheme such that the Weil restriction $Y:= R_l/k(X_l)$ exists, where $X_l$ is the base-change of $X$ to $l$. By definition of the Weil restriction, for any $k$-algebra $S$, we have 
$$ Y(S) \cong X_l(S_l)$$
(bijection as sets). My question is the following:

> What is this bijection explicitly? Should I think of a point $P \in Y(S)$ as a point in $X(S)$ base-changed to $X_l(S_l)$?

For some reason I find this very confusing!!

Comment: The bijection is part of the data of the Weil restriction.